# Proving a recursive relationship

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

this is the actual question

> Often poetic meters of some fixed beat length (per line) have some
>   rhythmic pattern composed of light and heavy syllables from the
>   source language (for example, English or Sanskrit). It is common to
>   treat the light syllable to measure as being 1 beat in length, while a
>   heavy syllable to measure as 2 beats.
>   In such a framework, given a fixed beat length of n, write a program
>   that can compute the total number of patterns involving light and/or
>   heavy syllables?
>   As an example, a line with a fixed beat length of 5 can be composed
>   of a pattern that is light-light-heavy-light (1+1+2+1=5),
>   or heavy-light-heavy (2+1+2=5), or any one of the other six possible
>   patterns.

Now I know this is a programming question but I realise that it is actually a fibonacci recursive relation where 
$f(N) = f(N-1) + f(N-2)$

My only problem is that I can't seem to prove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  A permissible sequence of length $n$ either begins with a light beat followed by a permissible sequence of length $n - 1$ or a heavy beat followed by a permissible sequence of length $n - 2$.

Comment: THANK YOU, i get it now
initially i wasnt considering the case where the beats begins with a heavy beat followed by a sequence of (n-2)